# Conditional on multiple insert

Tags: python, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a lot of records I need to insert into an already massive table (the table has several million rows and I'm inserting several thousand rows at a time).

The current syntax being used is a simple one:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (name, email) VALUES ('test','test@gmail.com'),('test2','test2@gmail.com')
```

These requests are made in batches of 1 thousand rows at a time.

For reasons outside of my control I do not have the ability to declare `email` as a unique column (the table already has duplicates).

How can I add a conditional to each INSERT request where we skip the inserts of an `email` when that value is found in the database?

So let's say in the above request we find we already have a row with email `test@gmail.com`. I would want to skip that row but still insert the other row (test2@gmail.com).

I'm struggling to find a syntax that works.

Using `SQL Server` and `pydb`.

Thanks in advance for any help! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should work

```
INSERT INTO my_table (name, email) 
SELECT name, email
FROM (VALUES ('test','test@gmail.com'),('test2','test2@gmail.com')) AS Vals(name, email)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM my_table x WHERE x.email = Vals.email)
```

An index on the email column will make this as fast as it can be, but it will still be slower than a normal insert.